# Looking for punctuations marks in a string and then finding their index to do a substring

Tags: java, string

I have some string where I need to extract a substring from it based on either the first occurrence of a punctuation mark or the first occurrence of a digit. E.g

from `Taltz 80mg autoinjector` I need to extract `Taltz` or from `Trulicity 0.75mg, weekly` I need to extract `Trulicity`

Here's my code:

```
 char [] punctuations = {'.' , ',' , ';' , ':','"' , '\'' ,'/', ')' , '('};

 String value = "Taltz, 80mg autoinjector";
 int pos = value.replaceFirst("^(\\D+).*$", "$1").length();     

                for(int j = 0; j < value.length(); j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k < punctuations.length;k++){
                        if(value.charAt(j) == punctuations[k]){
                            value = value.substring(0,value.indexOf(punctuations[k]));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            if(value.matches(".*\\d+.*")){
                value = value.substring(0, pos);
            }

            System.out.println(value);


        }
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: So, if the String is `I said, "Hello"`, then you want to extract `I said` ?

Comment: Do the strings always start with a word and you need to extract this word?

Comment: @ChandlerBing Exactly! These are medicine names I am trying to extract and the pattern name I found was that the medicine name is either followed by a punctuation mark or the dosage like 80 ml. So I am trying to extract based on these two assumptions.

Comment: @YuriHeiko In most cases yes but the medicine name could span multiple words too hnece using the dosage or punctuation mark as indicators.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the part that you want to keep and capture it with a regex :

```
String s = "Taltz test 80mg autoinjector";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z ]+).*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

if(matcher.matches()) {
  System.out.println("matches : " + matcher.group(1).trim());
} else {
  System.out.println("Does not match");
}
```

**Output** :

```
Taltz test
```

You can also capture everything that is "neither a punctuation sign nor a digit" with the following regex :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^0-9;,:.?]+).*");
```

(same output)

Comment: I just want to extract Taltz not Taltz test.  So this approach may not work. The pattern I have identified in my text is that the word I need to extract, in this case medicine name is either followed by a punctuation mark or the dosage of the medicine hence using either of these two as indicators I want to do a substring.

Comment: @serendipity why not "Taltz test" in above example? You commented that the name can "span multiple words", so why not in this case?

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger the correct name would be something like Paracip Hydrochloride - which refers to an entire drug name. In Taltz test the word test is junk value for me. hence I have to rely on patterns in which the drug names are occurring instead of a generic match which captures words and discards stuff that is neither a punctuation mark nor a digit.

Comment: @serendipity but how should the Java program "know" that "test" is a junk value? It clearly is not punctuation mark nor a digit

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I know. This is a tricky problem. Hence, one has to rely on patterns like "medicine name is either followed by a punctuation mark or the dosage of the medicine"

Comment: but by that last specification - either followed by a punctuation mark or the dosage -  having "Taltz test 80mg" must result in "Taltz test", which you wrote is wrong; so you must rethink your specification!